# Transposing named range from table, into another named range

Tags: excel, vba

I have this issue with taking named range in Worksheet "Team overview" (which is setup to table named "tbl", column no. 2), and then pasting it transposed into another named range in another worksheet called "Knowledge matrix" (could be solved by directing it to absolute reference, but in case I change number of columns in tables/worksheet I would need to update code in VBA).

I've tried using loop through array and only switching the x,y, coordinates, but the struggle I have is with copying that selection to another named range and assigning the source named range to variable rng (which returns run-time error 5 - Invalid procedure).

The code worked for testing file without named ranges and tables with just absolute references.

```
Sub Transpose()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngT As Range
Dim oarray As Variant
Dim cl As Long
Dim rw As Long

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Team overview").Range("Name")
Set rngT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Knowledge Matrix").Range("Target")

oarray = rng

For cl = 1 To UBound(oarray)    
    For rw = 1 To UBound(oarray, 2)    
        Cells(rw, cl) = oarray(cl, rw)    
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

The whole picture:

Table "tbl" is for a clear overview of team members. When the team lead adds/deletes one, I need it to be updated in all other table headers. Since headers cannot have formulas in them, I was thinking of copying the column in transposed way into named range for the other table headers.
There is also slight complication of condition the member being "Active" or "Butterfly", but that will be just cherry on the top.
So basically:

1. If column 1 has "Active" or "Butterfly" copy table/named range (Vertically spaced)
2. Transpose that array and paste it into another named array (Horizontally spaced)

I would prefer not to use `.Select` if possible.

Source table with named range
[image: Source table with named range]

Target table with named range
[image: Target table with named range]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a method called Transpose.

```
Sub MyTranspose()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngT As Range
    Dim oarray As Variant

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Team overview").Range("Name")
    Set rngT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Knowledge Matrix").Range("Target")

    oarray = rng.value2

    rngT.resize(ubound(oarray, 2), ubound(oarray, 1)) = _
        application.transpose(oarray)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, this helped. I've just had small issue, because I had it to be turned on by Worksheet change event, so it was as a private Sub and variable rngT returned error.  When I moved it to module, it had no issue. Thank you once again